# Firebase Emulator exported data corrupted on machine restart

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I typically start my emulator like this:

`firebase emulators:start --import=test/local-dev --export-on-exit=test/local-dev`

The aim: import data that was previously exported into the local-dev folder, and save any data when the emulator exits.

Upon restarting my dev machine (macOS Catalina), I can no longer use the data in local-dev folder as the emulator fails to start with this console output:

```
firestore: Fatal error occurred:
   Firestore Emulator has exited with code: 1,
   stopping all running emulators
```

The contents of firestore-debug.log:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.datastore.core.exception.DatastoreException: Failed to parse overall export metadata file
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.parseOverallMetadataFile(ExportImportUtil.java:229)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.fetchEntities(ExportImportUtil.java:56)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.CloudFirestore.main(CloudFirestore.java:89)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/project-root/test/local-dev/firestore_export/firestore_export.overall_export_metadata (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.parseOverallMetadataFile(ExportImportUtil.java:219)
        ... 2 more
```

I noticed that the `firestore_export` sub-folder that is typically in local-dev is missing:

```
$ ls test/local-dev/
firebase-export-metadata.json
```

It appears that the system shutdown process somehow corrupts the export folder. Any ideas how/why?